# C# Syntax Highlighting for System Types, not User Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I'm able to change the font color for User Types.  However, I can't find where to change the font color for User Types I didn't create; such as, of type "string".  Currently, my text editor displays these items using the same color as C# keywords (blue).

-Michael

Comment: I think Resharper allows for more variety in the types/keywords and how they're highlighted. But I don't know if it distinguishes C#-spec predefined type aliases (e.g., `int`, `string`, `object`, `long`, etc) or not.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a keyword, so I don't think you can change it to be colored as something else. That keyword happens to be an alias for the type `System.String`, but it is still a keyword. If it is possible to change it, would you like `var` to be coded differently if it refers to a built-in type as opposed to a user-defined type. And what is a system type? Any type defined in mscorlib?

Comment: I would definitely like to have control over the color for all possible type names that I didn't make.  'VAR' would still be part of that.  It would be nice to do that; instead of having them mixed in with all other keywords.